# Vimeo player crashing the ios ionic app as we exit from full screen

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, vimeo, vimeo-player, vimeo-ios

My Ionic app getting crash with Vimeo player. 
When we enter in fullscreen Vimeo player and exit from the fullscreen first time its working fine. But after we do the same task my ionic app goes to crash or exit.

As we debug with Xcode it shows me the memory exhaust issues.

How I can resolve this issue. I try every possible case but it still exits. I have tested in iPhone 6s, 6s plus, iPad, 7 plus. In all device same issue comes some time on the second attempt and some time in 3-4 attempt

Comment: We're having what I think is the same issue with our Cordova/Phonegap app. Any progress on this?

Comment: no. still in bug list